# PHP not posting to PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add info through a html form with a PHP script and get no errors and it runs through and acts like it is entering but nothing comes up on the database. Is there anyway from this code to tell if there is something that I am missing.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Kyrarose1";
$dbname = "Senior Project";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$ID = $_POST['ID'];
$ProjectTitle = $_POST['Project Title'];
$ProjectDescription = $_POST['Project Description'];
$ProjectObjective = $_POST['Project Objective'];
$ProjectScope = $_POST['Project Scope'];
$ProjectDate = $_POST['Date'];
$FirstName = $_POST['Firt name'];
$LastName = $_POST['Last name'];
$StudentId = $_POST['Student ID'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO ProjectObjectives ('ID','ProjectTitle', 'ProjectDescription', 'ProjectObjectives', 'ProjectScope', 'ProjectDate', 'Date', 'Fname', 'Lname', 'Student_Id') VALUES ('$ID', '$ProjectTitle', '$ProjectDecription', '$ProjectObjective' '$ProjectScope', '$ProjectDate', '$FirstName', '$LastName', '$StudentId')";



header("refresh:2; url=index.html");


?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<head>
<body>

        <form action="Insert.php" method="post">

            ID <input type="text" name="Id">
                            <br>
        Project Title: <input type="text" name="ProjectTitle" size="35">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        First Name: <input type="text" name="Fname">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        Last Name: <input type="text" name="Lname">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        Student ID: <input type="text" name="Student_Id">
                        <br>
                        <br/>


        Project Description: <input type="text" name="ProjectDescription">
                         <br>
                        <br/>

        Project Objective: <input type="text" name="ProjectObjective">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        Project Scope: <input type="text" name="ProjectScope">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        Date: <input type="text" name="Date">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        Milestones: <input type="text" name="Milestones">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        Deliverables: <input type="text" name="Deliverables">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        Date:<input type="text" name="Date">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        <br>Roles:<br/>

        <br><br/>

        Name: <input type="text" name="Name">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        Role: <input type="text" name="Role">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        Email: <input type="text" name="Email">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        Phone Number: <input type="text" name="Phone">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        Responsibilities: <input type="text" name="Responsibilities">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        <br>Resources:<br/>
        <br><br/>


        Resource: <input type="text" name="Resource">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        Hours: <input type="text" name="Hours">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        Risks: <input type="text" name="Risks">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        Strategy: <input type="text" name="Strategy">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

        Constraints: <input type="text" name="Constraints">
                        <br>
                        <br/>

                     <input type="submit" value="Submit">





        </form>
        </body>
        </head>
        </head>
        </html>
```

Comment: Errm, you're not executing the query after the SQL statement. Also, massive SQL injection risk. :)

Comment: I suggest you to learn more about php pdo http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: So now I have addedif (mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
header("refresh:2; url=index.html");

else {
  echo "not update";
}                 For some reason it is still not working.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not your database server. MySQL is your database server. You don't POST to phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Imagine someone posting something similar to `Robert'); DROP TABLE ProjectObjectives; --`  See: https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

You list 10 database columns in your INSERT statement, followed by only 9 values (variables) - that can't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is mysqli procedural style:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "xyz");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$x = "x";
$y = "y";
$z = "z";

/* create a prepared statement */
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO example324 (x,y,z) VALUES (?,?,?)");

    /* bind parameters for markers */
/* sss means has 3 corresponding variable type string */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $x, $y,$z);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

More about this here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php